# Reinstall Ubuntu Option

Tags: boot, dual-boot, reinstall

I have dual boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. Sometimes ubuntu doesn't work the way it used to work so i reinstall.
In the live boot, there is a option Reinstall Ubuntu 20. 04. Just asking, will it erase windows too? or just reinstall ubuntu on the same partition ( sda7)

Comment: it just reinstalls ubuntu on the same partition. Nothing wrong.